# Reference request random time changes representations and weak convergence

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

I was reading the Kurtz's book 'Markov Processes: Characterization and Convergence'
and I need to prove a similar theorem as theorem 1.5 on chapter 6 of that book, that basically states that if $Y$ is a random process with càdlàg sample paths, $\beta$ is a continuous function and $h>0$ then the process $X^h$ that is the solution of the equation 
$$X^h(t) = Y\left(\int_0^{\left\lfloor\frac{t}{h} \right\rfloor h}\beta(X^h(s)) \text{d}s\right)$$
converges weakly when $h \to 0$ to $X$  which is the solution of 
$$X(t) = Y\left(\int_0^t \beta(X(s))\text{d}s\right)$$
I really don't understand the proof that the book has and it would be great that there was a more clear proof in another place.

Any help will be appreciated